# Can I develop a WebXR with ARCore API for IOS?

Tags: html, ios, three.js, arcore, webxr

I have the following code below that works perfectly on android devices, but when I try to run on an IOS device, nothing happens when I click the button to start the ar session.I tried to get help from ChatGPT but it says that's all fine with the code, the problem might be device's compatibility or permissions, but I've checked this out and seems all fine, the device is an Iphone 13 that offers this kind of support. So i don't know what to do, don't even know if it's possible to run it on Iphone. Can someone help me? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js ar - hit test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="info">
            <a href="https://threejs.org" target="_blank" rel="noopener">three.js</a> ar - hit test<br/>(Chrome Android 81+)
        </div>

        <!-- Import maps polyfill -->
        <!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
        <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

        <script type="importmap">
            {
                "imports": {
                    "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                    "three/addons/": "./jsm/"
                }
            }
        </script>

        <script type="module">

            import * as THREE from 'three';
            import { ARButton } from 'three/addons/webxr/ARButton.js';

            let container;
            let camera, scene, renderer;
            let controller;

            let reticle;

            let hitTestSource = null;
            let hitTestSourceRequested = false;

            init();
            animate();

            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 20 );

                const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffff, 0xbbbbff, 1 );
                light.position.set( 0.5, 1, 0.25 );
                scene.add( light );

                //

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true, alpha: true } );
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                renderer.xr.enabled = true;
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //

                document.body.appendChild( ARButton.createButton( renderer, { requiredFeatures: [ 'hit-test' ] } ) );

                //

                const geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 32 ).translate( 0, 0.1, 0 );

                function onSelect() {

                    if ( reticle.visible ) {

                        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffffff * Math.random() } );
                        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                        reticle.matrix.decompose( mesh.position, mesh.quaternion, mesh.scale );
                        mesh.scale.y = Math.random() * 2 + 1;
                        scene.add( mesh );

                    }

                }

                controller = renderer.xr.getController( 0 );
                controller.addEventListener( 'select', onSelect );
                scene.add( controller );

                reticle = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.RingGeometry( 0.15, 0.2, 32 ).rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 ),
                    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
                );
                reticle.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
                reticle.visible = false;
                scene.add( reticle );

                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                renderer.setAnimationLoop( render );

            }

            function render( timestamp, frame ) {

                if ( frame ) {

                    const referenceSpace = renderer.xr.getReferenceSpace();
                    const session = renderer.xr.getSession();

                    if ( hitTestSourceRequested === false ) {

                        session.requestReferenceSpace( 'viewer' ).then( function ( referenceSpace ) {

                            session.requestHitTestSource( { space: referenceSpace } ).then( function ( source ) {

                                hitTestSource = source;

                            } );

                        } );

                        session.addEventListener( 'end', function () {

                            hitTestSourceRequested = false;
                            hitTestSource = null;

                        } );

                        hitTestSourceRequested = true;

                    }

                    if ( hitTestSource ) {

                        const hitTestResults = frame.getHitTestResults( hitTestSource );

                        if ( hitTestResults.length ) {

                            const hit = hitTestResults[ 0 ];

                            reticle.visible = true;
                            reticle.matrix.fromArray( hit.getPose( referenceSpace ).transform.matrix );

                        } else {

                            reticle.visible = false;

                        }

                    }

                }

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```